# How do i Subtract a duration from a time in Excel?

Tags: excel, time

I am having an issue with Excel and it’s probably very simple but I need to get a starting time by subtracting a duration from and end time.

For example say I know that an event needs to end at 1:55:23 pm and it will take 0:22:13 what formula would I use to find out what time I should start?

I would like to be able to input the duration in the format h:mm:ss without excel trying to turn it into a time and not a duration as well.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Try `TimeValue("1:55:23 pm") - TimeSerial(0, 22, 13)`.

Comment: OK, then `=TIMEVALUE("1:55:23 pm") - TIME(0, 22, 13)`

Answer (score 1):

You simply subtract them.

For example...

Cell A1 has the end time: 1:55:23 PM

Cell B1 has the duration: 0:22:13 (this is the only 'strange' part because it's actually an AM time, as in minutes after midnight... but if you think about it, that's what you want).

Cell C1 has this formula: =A1-B1

That's it.

NOTE: If your duration is longer than your event start time (for example, a 4-hour event that started at 3:00 in the morning!) then the subtraction would result in a negative time.

A negative time is OK in reality, but Excel will not display it as a formatted time... instead it displays a bunch of `############`. In that case, you need to display the calculation as a decimal value, which is the fraction of a day. For example. 0.25 means exactly 6 hours. If you would prefer decimal hours you simply multiply the fractional day figure by 24.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to mention that Excel will not display negative time. If the duration is more than the time, it can be displayed as a negative decimal but if formatted as time you will simply get `#########`.

Comment: Yes this is the problem i have run into exactly. So is there no way to have excel display it in a time format?

Comment: @REAPER.PHD You can try this: `=1+A1-B1`